# Finding Only Explicit Throws In Managed Code

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to wrap a legacy service for my API. The domain models that do CRUD operations in the service throw explicit standard exceptions like `ArgumentException` or `AggregateException` while also implicitly throwing them through failed stored procedures. I don't wish to expose information about the database or program through wrapping all exceptions, I just want to capture those that are thrown by past developers.

What's the best way capture explicit `throw new ArgumentException()` while avoiding the implicit `ArgumentException` thrown from a failed stored procedure?

Comment: From your question I surmise you are looking for ALL ArgumentExceptions that originate within your managed project code, rather than excluding only those that are from failed SQL calls. I am interested to see what others come up with but I am not sure there is a clean way to do this short of looking at the call stack within the exception and doing some nasty parsing.

Comment: @Theo That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to catch it as SqlException first and then ArgumentExceptions after? Just a stab.

Comment: Why not throw custom exceptions?

Comment: @GibralterTop That's why I added clarification in my comment. Richard is looking to catch all exceptions that were thrown outside of his code-base, not just those that occurred on SQL calls.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos it's legacy, and in production unfortunately.  I'm just building a wrapper around it for an API

Comment: Throwing custom exceptions would be the way to go, however it would involve chasing down all existing `throw new` statements and replacing them (not so bad) and then chasing down the call stack to see if/how each might be handled and updating it to catch the new exception type (that would be a nightmare)

Comment: @Theo I think if the custom Exception inherits from ArgumentException I believe existing catch statements should be OK,so you avoid the  nightmare(if I'm not mistaken...)

Comment: @Richard Have you checked the "Source"/"Stacktrace" properties to see if  there is anything there to help you identify them?

Comment: @GeorgeVovos You make a good point, that could get Richard where he needs to be provided his problem is limited to ArgumentExceptions.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos the stack trace doesn't look anything different to me.  Some of the code has `return new Foo(){--Properties--}` that fail, so the stacktrace ends up looking the same.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I ended up going with your solution of throwing custom exceptions that are just inheritors of the generic exceptions they used to be.  If you could please put your suggestion as a full-on answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably noticed there isn't a way to catch just explicit throws.
The safest way to solve your problem is to throw a custom exception that inherits from your original.
This way you can handle the explicit throws and you don't break any existing try/catch statements